# Delete rows on different worksheets (No loop)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm a beginner is coding, and im trying to figure something out.

I want to delete rows on different worksheets defined in an inputbox.

My code is only working on sheet 1. And not on Sheet 2. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?

```
Sub RemovingRowsFromDifferentSheets()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim Wsheet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wsheet = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range you want to delete across multiple sheets:", "Removing defined range", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Sheets("Worksheet 1 ").Select
    rng.Delete


    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Select
    rng.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you remove or comment out `On Error Resume Next` and then use F8 to step through each line of code?

Comment: Object required on the last rng.delete

Comment: `rng` in your context is on `ActiveSheet`.  When you do the first `rng.Delete` the `rng` object is destroyed.  When you try to do `rng.Delete` there is no `rng` object because it's already been deleted.

Comment: I thought it was something like that, but how can you move further without having to enter the rows again via the inputbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing code from scratch or cleaning up macro-recorded code it's good practice to avoid some things if possible:

- `On Error Resume Next` can allow code to run but it's like sweeping dust under the rug - the errors are still there but you can't see them.  Results can be unpredictable!  It's far better to allow the errors to be seen and address them before they occur.
- `ActiveSheet` may not be the sheet you think it is.  It may not even be in the workbook you think it is!
- `Select` can also provide unpredictable results.  In your code `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Select` does `Select` and `Activate` Worksheet2 but it does nothing to the `rng` object.

Be specific when setting or defining variables and applying methods to them.

**Always** declare `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.  You can force VBA to do this by going to Tools -> Options... and clicking the Require Variable Declaration box.  This is not retrospective - it doesnt apply to existing modules.

To make you code work as intended by deleting row(s) on specific sheets you need the `Address` of your `rng` object.  Note that `rng` is specific to the sheet and selection when you click OK in the InputBox.  You (or the user) could select a different sheet while the InputBox is active.  What you actually need to work with is the `rng.Address` which can be put into a `String` variable that can still be used after `rng` has been deleted.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemovingRowsFromDifferentSheets()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngAddr As String
    Dim Wsheet As Worksheet

    'On Error Resume Next  **Use with extreme care**
    Set Wsheet = ActiveSheet  'Set but never used.
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range you want to delete across multiple sheets:", "Removing defined range", Type:=8)
    'Make sure the selection is in the expected workbook.
    'The parent of a range is its worksheet object
    'The parent of a worksheet object is its workbook object
    If rng.Parent.Parent.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        rngAddr = rng.Address
        'Specify which workbook will be modified
        With ThisWorkbook
            'Delete rows
            .Sheets("Worksheet 1 ").Range(rngAddr).EntireRow.Delete
            .Sheets("Worksheet2").Range(rngAddr).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

The code assumes that "Worksheet 1 " (with a trailing space) and "Worksheet2" (with no spaces) actually exist in ThisWorkbook.  You could probably build some error handling in case they don't but that's another question.

Also, you don't need to test `If rng Is Nothing` because `Application.InputBox` won't let you click Cancel and if you click OK without making a selection, it pops an error message redirecting you back to the InputBox.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

I want to thank you for this code and the clear explanation of it.

This one works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

**This simple VBA code (Macro) will help you to delete desires Rows across multiple sheets, without any Loop.**

```
Sub DelRowMulSht()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Set xWs = ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Select
    Rows("1:15").Select
    Selection.Delete
    xWs.Select
End Sub
```

**Note:**

*Use this code as **Standard Module**.*

*Rows to Delete `Rows("1:15").select` is editable, you can set any dimension as your need.*